# Matplotlib - Chart using patch circles with size equivalent to error bars. Scaling issue. Circles are squashed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a chart using patches.  From the code below, does anyone know why these would end up being squashed and not circular, like I want?  Unfortunately I do not have enough rep to post a picture... sample code is self contained, i.e. you should be able to run it to generate graph.  Patches seem to change shape when plot is resized.  I would like them to stay fixed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

mypath = ['1,0.25','2,0.5','3,0.35','4,0.40']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
Distances = []
Confidence_Intervals = []

for line in mypath:
    Distances.append(float(line.split(',')[0].strip()))
    Confidence_Intervals.append(float(line.split(',')[1].strip()))

ind = np.arange(len(Distances))
data = np.array(Distances)
y_error = np.array(Confidence_Intervals)
circles = []

for a in range(len(ind)):
    ax.scatter(0, data[a], s=60, color='Black')
    trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transData)
    circles.append(patches.Circle((0,data[a]),y_error[a], transform=trans,facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5))

fig.set_size_inches(24,12)
for circle in circles:
    ax.add_patch(circle)

plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc=0, scatterpoints = 1)
plt.ylabel('Pairwise distance (FastTree)')
plt.xlabel('Clade pairing')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=8)
plt.title(title)
plt.xlim(-0.6,0.6)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you fix your indentation, please?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you provide a self-contained example, which we can run directly. Furthermore, your code is very long. You'll get faster replies if you narrow your problem down to a couple of lines.

Comment: Looking at the code, It seems like you're changing the ylimits after you create the circles. If you told me that patches wouldn't cope with that correctly, I'd believe you.  You might need to compute the limits first and then add the patches.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys.  I'll try suggestions and provide a self contained example.

Comment: It sounds like you want `plt.axis('equal')` (or `ax.set(aspect=1.0)` if you don't want to have the y and x limits set to be the same.).

Comment: Adding the following seems to fix my problem:  axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')  
It was because the aspect ratio of the sub plot was not being set.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion Joe Kington.  You were right.  The aspect ratio was not being set.

I added the following line:

axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')

The patches are now keeping their width independently of chart size.  Final code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

mypath = ['1,0.25','2,0.5','3,0.35','4,0.40']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
Distances = []
Confidence_Intervals = []

for line in mypath:
    Distances.append(float(line.split(',')[0].strip()))
    Confidence_Intervals.append(float(line.split(',')[1].strip()))

ind = np.arange(len(Distances))
data = np.array(Distances)
y_error = np.array(Confidence_Intervals)
circles = []
print y_error
plt.xlim(-0.6,0.6)

for a in range(len(ind)):
    ax.scatter(0, data[a], s=60, color='Black')
    trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transData)
    circles.append(patches.Circle((0,data[a]),y_error[a], transform=trans, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5))

fig.set_size_inches(24,12)
for circle in circles:
    ax.add_patch(circle)

plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc=0, scatterpoints = 1)
plt.ylabel('Pairwise distance (FastTree)')
plt.xlabel('Clade pairing')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=8)
plt.title(title)
axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.show()
```